# How to make the child's of a parent div focusable but not the grandchild divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to make all the children of the parent `div` focusable but not the grandchildren.

Like this:

```
<div class="parent" >
<div class="child1" > <!-- should be focused-->
<div class="grandchild" ></div> <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
</div>
<div class="child2" > <!-- should be focused-->
<div class="grandchild" ></div> <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
</div>
<div class="child3" > <!-- should be focused-->
<div class="grandchild" ></div> <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
</div>
<div class="child4" > <!-- should be focused-->
<div class="grandchild" ></div> <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
</div>
<div class="child5" > <!-- should be focused-->
<div class="grandchild" ></div> <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
<!-- more divs-->
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it with pure HTML, CSS?

Does using `tabindex=0`on the parent div make all the children focusable? Or do I need to individually add a `tabindex` to each of the children?

Using the tab button on keyboard

Comment: what do yo mean by focused? Like able to be tabbed to?

Comment: Yes by using the keyboard button.

Comment: If you want to add some CSS styles you can use `parent > .child` (given all the children have a child class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `tab-index` to `-1` prevents the element from being focused by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This can be automated with JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.parent > * > *').forEach((e)=>{
  e.setAttribute("tabindex", -1);
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <!-- should be focused-->
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <!-- should be focused-->
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <!-- should be focused-->
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
  </div>
  <div class="child4">
    <!-- should be focused-->
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
  </div>
  <div class="child5">
    <!-- should be focused-->
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <!-- shouldn't be focused-->
    <!-- more divs-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I make all the child divs focusable like do I add `tabindex=0` to the parent?

Comment: This won't work in cases like where your grandchild div has focussable element like button.

Comment: That's alright since I need buttons to be focusable.

Comment: @Dumdum you could set `tabindex=0`, `tabindex=1`, etc..

Comment: So I have to set the tabindex to all the children individually? I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way of settings the tabindex.

Comment: You can use a bit of javascript ! 
let grandchild = document.getElementsByClassName('grandchild') ;

for (let i = 0; i <= grandchild.length; i++){
  grandchild[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '-1') ;
}

Comment: @Dumdum I've updated my answer. You can automate the process with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex),

- **Only interactive components must have a tab index.**
- **Avoid using tabindex values greater than 0**.

A positive `tabindex` on an element makes it focusable, but this focusability is not inherited by each of its children.

In pure html, I think there is no way to make each child of an element focusable unless you add a `tabindex="0"` on them. The easiest way is to use javascript by doing something like

```js
/// make elements focusable
Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".focusable")
).forEach(item => item.tabIndex = 0);

/// make elements not focusable
Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".grandchild")
).forEach(item => item.tabIndex = -1);
```